# Finding if a path between two words in a list exists

Tags: python, recursion, return

I have a problem that I am trying to solve, which is, I have a list of words:

```
word_list = ["DATA", "TATA", "PAPA", "PATA", "TOTO", "TITI", "TATI", "TUTO", "DARA", "DORA"]
```

I want to return `True` if a path between two words exists. The change from one word to another should be by replacing one char.
For instance, the paths between "DATA" and "PAPA" are:

`DATA -> TATA -> PATA -> PAPA`

`DATA -> PATA -> PAPA`

The code below prints all the existing paths, where I used the recursion function to do that. How can I change it to `return True|False` if a path exists or not (inside `find_graph_words` function)? The recursion function confuses me sometimes when I want to use return.

```
def count_diff(source, target):
    diff = 0
    for c1, c2 in zip(source, target):
        if c1 != c2:
            diff += 1
    return diff

def compute_distances(word_list):
    distances = {}
    for word in word_list:
        for target in word_list:
            if word in distances:
               maps = distances[word]
               maps[target] = count_diff(word, target)
               distances[word] = maps
            else:
               distances[word] = {target: count_diff(word, target)}
    return distances

def find_graph_words(source, target, distances, path):
    path += source + ' -> '
    to_visit = [item for item in word_list if (distances[source][item] == 1) and (item not in path)]
    if target in to_visit:
        path += target
        print(path)
    for node in to_visit:
        find_graph_words(node, target, distances, path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_list = ["DATA", "TATA", "PAPA", "PATA", "TOTO", "TITI", "TATI", "TUTO", "DARA", "DORA"]
    distances = compute_distances(word_list)
    find_graph_words("DATA", "PAPA", distances, '')
```

Comment: Typically you need to determine a base case (when you want recursion to stop) then when the base case is reached ***it*** should return what is required (you said `True` or `False`). Then you also return the return value of the recursive call - e.g. `return find_graph_words(node, target, distances, path)`. Your function may need to some work to accomplish this. Are you sure you need recursion?

Comment: If the goal is to return `True` or `False` the code is poorly written. There is a work around, but I would recommend recoding this with the purpose of returning `True` or `False`. Then you can just use `if source == target: return True`.

Comment: @wwii is there a way other than recursion?

Comment: @EliHarold , and what for the `return False` case?

Comment: @Minions you are far from getting there with the current code so it is not worth explaining. tricot's answer is worth looking at.

Comment: Is there a path from a word to itself? That's your base case. Knowing the neighbours of the current word, and being able to check for paths from those to the target, *what is the rule that tells you* whether there is a path from the current word to the target? That's your recursive step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your existing code, `item not in path` could give wrong outcomes when shorter strings are found in longer strings (if that is possible to have in your graph). It would be better to use a list or set structure for your path.

For testing the existence only of a path, you can exit the loop as soon as you get a hit from recursion:

```
def connected(source, target, distances, path):
    to_visit = [item for item in word_list if distances[source][item] == 1 and item not in path]
    if target in to_visit:
        return True
    for node in to_visit:
        if connected(node, target, distances, path + [node]):
            return True
    return False
```

This can be reduced to:

```
def connected(source, target, distances, path):
    to_visit = [item for item in word_list if distances[source][item] == 1 and item not in path]
    return target in to_visit or any(
        connected(node, target, distances, path + [node])
        for node in to_visit
    )

word_list = ["DATA", "TATA", "PAPA", "PATA", "TOTO", "TITI", "TATI", "TUTO", "DARA", "DORA"]
distances = compute_distances(word_list)
print(connected("DATA", "PAPA", distances, []))
```

You can improve the efficiency of determining `to_visit`, by creating an adjacency list first, instead of a distances matrix, where the adjacency list will only have the edges where the distance is 1.

Comment: Thanks @trincot! I don't have solid algorithm background; i find it hard to understand why we need another if statement with return: `if connected(node, target, distances, path + [node]):`. I already returned `True` or `False` inside the function!

Comment: Yes, but when that  `True` comes back to the one who made the recursive call, there is no need to continue looking (i.e. looping). At that moment the final answer is known, so you want to exit *now* and forward that same  `True` upwards the recursion tree and exit as fast as possible. If you would continue looping, you would always end up returning `False` and ignore the `True` you once got from a recursive call. Surely you don't want that to happen ;-)

Comment: Thanks trincot! now I got it :) .. just a final small question plz: what is the run time complexity of your first solution?

Comment: If *n* is the number of words, and *k* the number of letters in a word (or the maximum if it varies), then `compute_distances` will have O(*n*²*k*) time complexity. `connected` may have a worst case (where everything is connected with distance 1, except the target) of O(*n*³). This could be improved. If you have questions about any of this, I suggest you ask a new question.